# File reading line by line in c#

Tags: c#, readfile

I'm reading 2 inputs from text file input.txt. I have text file as

> 12#15#
>
> 17#71#
>
> 18#15#

I have used this syntax but it reads last line only.why it isn't working? what may be the best loop condition to read line bye line like 12+15 and show 27 and read next line 17+71 and show 88 and process last

```
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.txt");
            string line;
            int count = 0;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] splitted = line.Split('#');
                string first = splitted[0].Trim();
                string second = splitted[1].Trim();
                x = Convert.ToInt32(first);
                y = Convert.ToInt32(second);
```

Comment: So do you want to sum all the rows and show it then?

Comment: You can't add strings.  The + symbol is a concatenation. You need to convert the strings to integers, and then do your summation.  Cast that summation back to a string and then display it.

Comment: @ZaXa, wow, i didn't noticed that, that's quite novice questioon :)

@sangam-jung   use `sum = Convert.ToInt32(first) + ....`    etc

Comment: You want to sum all values in the file and then display it? in this case you want to show the sum of 12+15+17+71+18+15?

Comment: Have you realised that you are only trying to add last two values (18+15)? Is that what you want?

Comment: @KosalaW thats what i'm talking about. this loop is reading only the last values not others

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro I want to add 12+15,  17+71 and 18+15 separately

Comment: @SangamJung Now I understand the problem. This needs only two lines of coding. But the question is on-hold. So we can't help you. You may have to edit the topic of the question and word your question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**General answer**
You should append to text box, but you are overwriting it in each loop iteration.

I'd suggest to move txtSum.Text assignment out of the loop, to be operated only once, as txtSum.set_Text is Operation that involves graphics repaint and is expensive.

**Sample**

```
try
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.txt");
    string line;
    StringBuilder sum = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] splitted = line.Split('#');
        string first = splitted[0].Trim();
        string second = splitted[1].Trim();
              sum.Append(first).Append(second);

    }
        txtSum.Text = sum.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I have updated the previous one